# Как положить данные из переменных внутрь локального массива

Tags: php

Есть функция внутри, которой находятся три переменных(сам массив и две переменные с данными)
Как внутри функции запихнуть данные из **$name и $age в массив $massive,**
а потом вывести все это в echo.

**То есть, чтобы echo выводил "Test" и "23"**
Моя попытка внизу, что писать в цикле я не понимаю =(

```js
function fun() {   
 
$massive = [];
 
$name = "test";
$age = 23;
 
foreach($massive as ){
   
}
 
return $massive;
};
 
echo fun();
```

Comment: Сколько книжек по PHP вы прочитали, прежде чем писать какой-либо код?

Comment: и тишинаааааааа

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Судя по коду и бессмысленности задачи - топикстартер тут уже был. Но знаний видимо не почерпнул.

Answer (score 0):

я сам новичок, так что если будут читать ПРО извиняйте)

На мой новичковый взгляд функция не место для хранения переменный, функция содержит набор действий которые что-то делают с переменными.

```js
$name = "test";
$age = 23;

function fun( $a, $b ) {    // -------создаем функцию которая принимает две переменных

   $massive = [];     // -------------создаем пустой массив
   array_push( $massive, $a, $b ); //--и кладем в него наши переменные
   
   return $massive;    // ------------возвращаем массив с переменными

}

/*т.к. функция возвращает нам массив, мы можем пройтись по нему Форычем,
 и вывести элементы массива через пробел. Для этого внутри Форыча вызываем 
 функцию (и передаем в неё наши переменные Name и Age):*/
  
foreach ( fun($name, $age) as $item ) { 
    echo $item . ' ';
}

// или можем просто вывести сам массив. Для этого вызываем функцию внутри Принта:
print_r( fun($name, $age) );
```